# Get value inside Listenner in android

Tags: java, android, listener

I have some code like this:

```
 final int height = 0; //I want to get this height after Predraw view
 view.addOnPreDrawListener(new OnPreDrawListener()
    {

        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw()
        {
            int myHeight = itemLayout.getMeasuredHeight();
            height = myHeight; //this line has error
            return false;
        }
    });
```

The prolem is how I can get value (especially primitive type) from the listenner. It always shows

```
 Cannot refer to a non-final variable height inside an inner class defined in a different method
```

Then I try to change variable to final, it shows the error:

```
 The final local variable height cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type
```

I don't know why the APIs are difficult to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to deal with this is by letting your `Activity` implement `OnPreDrawListener`.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnPreDrawListener{
  int height;

  method(){
    ..
    view.addOnPreDrawListener(this);
    ..
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onPreDraw(){
    height = itemLayout.getMeasuredHeight();
  }  
}
```

The issue is not with the 'complexity' of the API. This is a real Java problem regarding the life of the various variables involved. By not declaring the variable `height` final, it might be cleaned off the stack by the time your inner anonymous class tries to access it. By having to mark it `final`, you are being forced to guarantee the life of `height`.

By doing what I suggested, you are equating the life of the Activity object and the listener Object.

Answer (score 3):

declare it as **global**    `int myHeight;`  before `onCreate(....)`

Comment: @R4j: do u get the solution ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use "final" on the initialisation of height and then attempt to change it later. You could however assign the variable to the class instead of within the function.

```
private int tmpHeight = 0;
```

This would allow you to access the variable from within the listener.

Answer (score 2):

Both error mentioned by you are correct

1) non-final variable cannot be accessed inside the inner class

2) final variable can not be change after initialization

declare height as global variable inside class and not in any method will solve your problem

```
 int myHeight;
```

Answer (score 1):

Making it a class level variable is also an option.

Answer (score 1):

the error is not in the listener, it's in the declaration of the `height` as a final variable.

the meaning of that is that it cannot be changed after the initialization, you have to remove the final from it:

```
int height = 0; 
view.addOnPreDrawListener(new OnPreDrawListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onPreDraw() {
        int myHeight = itemLayout.getMeasuredHeight();
        height = myHeight; 
        return false;
    }
});
```